# Can OpenSSL::PKey::RSA object instance be shared between Ruby threads?

Tags: ruby, openssl

Is it ok to share `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` object instance between multiple threads (i.e. by assigning it to a constant), or should each Ruby thread use a separate instance of `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` object?

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes. The default behavior for all Ruby code (even with wrapped C libraries like OpenSSL) is to run only one Ruby Thread at a time. So by default it is not possible for two Threads to access the same object at the same time in a dangerous way.

However, for C extensions, there are ways to disable this protection so that you can actually have true parallelism between Threads, but ideally that should only be used for certain critical portions that the gem authors know are thread-safe.

Basically you don't need to worry about crashing Ruby by sharing objects across threads. But especially for objects implemented in Ruby, it is possible for their methods to run concurrently in different threads, which could lead to surprising results. If you want that kind of thread safety guarantee use a Mutex no matter what kind of object you're using.

Comment: What do you mean "in general"? In general the Global Interpreter Lock does not prevent thread-safety problems and that's why we have libs such as https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby which contain i.e. thread-safe Hash implementation etc.

Comment: The VM itself locks down unsafe access of Ruby types. It is not possible to _crash_ the Ruby VM by having a ton of threads simultaneously mutate a shared Ruby object. But if you do that, the object may end up in a weird final state since the _atomicity_ of operations is not guaranteed. The library you linked addresses that specific problem by providing types where every method is atomic.

Comment: For C extensions that implement methods in C code, the default behavior is even more stringent: methods _are_ atomic by default since the Ruby VM has no idea if that C code is safe to run concurrently with other Ruby stuff.